# How to get no. of zeroes - no. of poles in argument principle?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Statement**: Suppose that $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is meromorphic in an open set containing a circle C with its interior. Suppose that $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$.Then,
$\displaystyle\int_C \dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\mathrm{d}z= 2\pi i (n_0-n_p)$ , where $\qquad\displaystyle{n_0:=\text{"number of zeros of }f\text{ inside }C" \atop n_p:= \text{"the number of poles inside }\mathbb C"}$.
This is called the argument principle in complex analysis.

Now, my confusion lies in its proof which follows from the following:

If $f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$, then $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}= \dfrac{n}{z-z_0} + h(z)$, where $h$ is holomorphic in a nbd around $z_0$; and if $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at some $z_1$ then $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}= -\dfrac{n}{z-z_1} + g(z)$, where $g$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood around $0$.

According to the above, I don't understand how one gets $n_0$ and $n_p$ in the argument principle.
I think that instead one should get $n_0=$ the sum of orders of all zeroes inside $\mathbb C$, and $n_p=$ the sum of all orders of all poles inside $\mathbb C$. This is because of the presence of $n$ in $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ above and $n$ was chosen to be order of zero at $z_0$ for example.

Please help me understand how to get $n_0$ and $n_p$ as stated in the statement. Thanks.

Comment: Please spell princip*le* correctly. ... On a more serious note, such counts — $n_0$ being the "number of zeroes" — *always* mean counting multiplicities. There is no problem here.

Comment: Yes you have to count with the multiplicity of the zeroes/poles. It’s just an (implicitly understood) abuse of language if people say otherwise.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: "Suppose $f$ has no zeros and poles on $\mathbb{C}$" : simple mistake allows Cauchy to make the integral $0$.

Comment: @user977780 fixed. Thanks a lot :-).

Comment: Let me sketch the proof:

Call $g(z) =\frac{f'(z) }{f(z) }$

Observation: Singularities of $g$ at a point $z_0$ can occur in two ways: 

 1) $z_0$ is a zero of $f $

2) $z_0$ is a singularity of $f$ 

Note: These are the only ways$[$hint: $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ and $f(z_0) \neq 0$ implies $g$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ $]$ $g$ can achieve singularity at $z_0$.

Comment: Case $1$ : $z_0$ is a zero of $f$ of order $n$ i.e $(z-z_0) ^n\mid\mid f(z) $

Claim $1$: $g$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ and $\textrm{res}(f;z_0) =n$

Hint: $z_0$ is a zero of $f'$ of order $n-1$

Case $2$: $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ of order $m$ and $\textrm{res}(f;z_0) =-m$

Claim $2$ : $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$.

Hint: $z_0$ is a pole of order $m+1$ of $f'$.

____
$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int_C \dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\mathrm{d}z&=2\pi i\sum_{z_0\in\mathcal{S}}\textrm{res}(f, z_0)\\&=2\pi i(n+(-m))\end{align}$

Comment: Hint: write $f$ as a product of functions which each have at most one zero-or-pole in $C$, then use $\frac{(fg)'}{fg}=\frac{f'}{f}+\frac{g'}{g}$.